# AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode causes infinitely loop & flickerring on some devices

Tags: android

when I put
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode to Night Mode
before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

and the System Force Stop

It causes flickering and keep restart the activity.

This only happens on certain devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving the looping problem by eliminating the forced Day Mode in the Login Page.

The primary issue revolves around the AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode of both the Login Page and Main Page. While the Login Page was configured to enforce Day Mode, the Main Page was set in DayNight Mode. Causing them to override with each other thus looping